# .Net URI is encoded incorrectly

Tags: c#, vb.net, url, httpwebrequest, uri

I need to parse `http://website.com/page?id=ABCD | EFG`:

```
Dim WebR As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(URL), HttpWebRequest)
```

Any normal browser (Such as firefox) would encode the URL like this: `http://website.com/page?id=ABCD%20|%20EFG`

However, when using the code I provided or creating a new URI, the URL gets encoded into:`http://website.com/page?id=ABCD%20%7C%20EFG`

Which wont work for me because that `id` doesnt exist.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: and btw: `ABCD%20%7C%20EFG` **is** the correct representation of that string; chrome and internet explorer get this right; if firefox is retaining the `|`, then arguably: firefox is simply wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is: don't start with an illegal url. If you are constructing the url yourself, it is your job to escape the components. For example:

```
string id = "ABCD | EFG"; // perhaps via some more complicated code
string url = "http://website.com/page?id=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(id);
```

This outputs, correctly, `http://website.com/page?id=ABCD%20%7C%20EFG`. This is the **correct** url. `|` is not a valid character in a url.

From https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2, the unreserved characters are *defined* as:

```
unreserved  = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
```

where `ALPHA` is defined as `A`-`Z` and `a`-`z`, and `DIGIT` is defined as `0`-`9`.

Anything else needs to be %-encoded.